# Count the number of times a string appears

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to calculate the number of times a brand appears. I have researched a lot and I found out that maybe need to use **count()**. But how do I apply into this situation?

```
favourites = conn.execute('SELECT Favourite.id, Favourite.smartphoneID, Smartphone.brand, Smartphone.model, Smartphone.lowprice, Smartphone.highprice, Smartphone.image_URL FROM Favourite INNER JOIN Smartphone ON Favourite.userID = ? AND Favourite.smartphoneID = Smartphone.id',(userid)).fetchall()
for favourite in favourites:
    print(favourite[2])
```

Based on the output below, my expected result is the **count of Apple should be 2 and Samsung should be 1**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:12:54] "GET /static/smartphone.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:12:54] "GET /static/iphone13.webp HTTP/1.1" 304 -
Apple
Samsung
Apple
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:13:00] "GET /favourite HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:13:00] "GET /static/smartphone.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:13:00] "GET /static/iphone14.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:13:00] "GET /static/samsung-galaxy-S21-5G.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022 19:13:00] "GET /static/iphone13.webp HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: You are looking for [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

actually you solved the question, but stuck in a simple place :)

Let me show you how to count all fields in the list;

```
sample_list = ["apple", "apple", "Samsung"]

counts = {key:sample_list.count(key) for key in set(sample_list)}
print(counts)

# output: {"apple": 2, "Samsung": 1}
```

Comment: The question is how to retrieve brand count from the database, not how to count items in an in-memory list